# No way to delete a specific mapping/type?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I see that DELETE /[index]/[type]/_mapping is no longer supported. And it's recommended to delete the entire index. Curious why this is, or if there's a workaround. If a specific type changes, we don't really want to have to re-sync the entire index, including all types/mappings.

Comment: If you go [one type per index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type), then deleting a mapping type boils down to simply deleting the index itself. Why do you need to delete the mapping type in the first place (field type change, etc)? If you simply want to empty the index you can use [delete-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) instead.

Comment: Yes, we have some types which have dynamic fields (e.g. customized attributes). So if a new attribute is added or an existing one changes, we need to push a new mapping with those changes, and then re-index all instances of that type. We considered that we could switch to one-type-per-index, and it may be what we have to end up doing, but it would complicate (in theory) cross-type searches. I'm curious if this is the recommended use case or if there's any details regarding _why_ deleting a type is no longer possible.

Comment: Yes, it was explained in this [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring) a while ago. In short, it's mainly to prevent index corruption.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.